# how to give space in horizontal scroll i want space after last cell

Tags: react-native

at end of flatlist padding right and margin right is not effective its not showing space after end of flatlist i am using horizontal flat list

```
<FlatList
      horizontal
      contentInset={{right: 20}}
      pagingEnabled={true}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      data={item.listData}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => {
        var lastCell =
          mainListData.length - 1 == index ? true : false;
        var firstCell = index == 0 ? true : false;
        console.log(firstCell, lastCell);
        return (
          <CategoryComponent
            data={item}
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('RecipeList');
            }}
            isLastCell={lastCell}
            isFirstCell={firstCell}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
```

## category component returns below style

```
 <TouchableOpacity
    style={{
    width: 'auto',
      marginLeft: isFirstCell
        ? 0.064 * deviceWidth
        : 0.043 * deviceWidth,
      marginRight: isLastCell ? 0.064 * deviceWidth : 0
    }}
    onPress={onPress}>
    <View style={styles.showCollectionnView}>
      <Image source={data.image}
        style={{
          height: 144,
          width: 144,
          borderRadius: 10,
          position: 'absolute'
        }}/>
    </View>
    <Text style={styles.nameText}>{data.name}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.otherText}>{data.recipes}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use contentContainer style for flatlist

```
<FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={{paddingRight:100}}
    //... other props
/>
```

You can increase as per your requirement.